# error while executing query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Getting error while executing following query in access 2007, how to solve this?

my query is :

```
SELECT
          A.PRODUCT
        , A.DISPBANK
        , COUNT(*) AS RecCount
        , SUM(Amt) AS TotAmt
FROM
          CBWCFAPENDINGPAYMENTDATA A
WHERE
          A.MATCH     ='Y'
          AND A.ID LIKE'*(SELECT [CASHIN_ID] FROM CBWCFAMISUPLOAD WHERE VENDOR='BRINKS' AND NZ(MATCH,'')='Y')*'
GROUP BY
          A.PRODUCT
        , A.DISPBANK
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give exmple of data in your tables, and explain what results you are trying to return please?

Comment: There's no space between `Like` and `'` - `LIKE'*(SELECT ....`.  Also - can you use a `Select` statement like that within a `Like` (asking as not sure)?

Comment: also you should be using double quotes not single

Comment: i'm trying to return distinct columns data from CBWCFAPENDINGPAYMENTDATA table where MATCH column should be 'Y' and id comes from CBWCFAMISUPLOAD table they may be single id or multiple id thats y place like there

Comment: ok in that case yes you can check for the string in your like clause, but you need to use double quotes not single in access, this will be the issue

Comment: I think really you should be testing the reults of another query in your where clause here though:    SELECT A.PRODUCT, A.DISPBANK,Count(*) as RecCount,Sum(Amt) as TotAmt FROM CBWCFAPENDINGPAYMENTDATA A WHERE A.MATCH='Y' AND 
A.ID IN (SELECT [CASHIN_ID] FROM CBWCFAMISUPLOAD WHERE VENDOR='BRINKS' AND NZ(MATCH,'')='Y')) GROUP BY A.PRODUCT, A.DISPBANK

Comment: but can in return result if the  id column have single value

Comment: it shows data type mismatch in criteria expression error!

Comment: this will return all rows from CBWCFAPENDINGPAYMENTDATA  where a match on the ID is found in CBWCFAMISUPLOAD, if there are more than one row with a match then use distinct to limit your results

Comment: check the data types you are compaing between the tables so what data type is CASHIN_ID and what datatype is ID?

Comment: cashin_ID is string how do i mess with it.. please tell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142903/discussion-between-vivek-padelkar-and-jimmy8ball).

Comment: whats is the other dt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a subquery inside the LIKE string.

You could use DLookup and string concatenation for this.

```
AND A.ID LIKE '*' & 
  DLookup("[CASHIN_ID]", "CBWCFAMISUPLOAD", "VENDOR='BRINKS' AND NZ(MATCH,'')='Y'" ) & '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so your answer should be like the below, and will calculate what you need if the tables have a one to many relationship,  and returns all rows from table a where the id is found in table b:

```
     SELECT A.PRODUCT, A.DISPBANK,Count(*) as RecCount,Sum(Amt) as TotAmt FROM CBWCFAPENDINGPAYMENTDATA A WHERE A.MATCH="Y" AND Format(CStr([A.ID])) IN (SELECT [CASHIN_ID] FROM CBWCFAMISUPLOAD WHERE VENDOR="BRINKS" AND NZ(MATCH,"")="Y")) GROUP BY A.PRODUCT, A.DISPBANK
```